# how to parse xml string attribute in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

i have this bit complicated xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from catkin_ws/src/steer_bot/steer_bot_description/urdf/steer_bot.urdf.xacro | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->



<robot name="steer_bot">
  
  </material>
  <material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="dark_gray">
    <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="gray">
    <color rgba="0.753 0.753 0.753 1"/>
  </material>
  <!-- Gazebo plugins -->
  <gazebo>
    <!-- Load ros_control plugin using the steer_bot_hardware_gazebo
    implementation of the hardware_interface::RobotHW -->
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so" name="gazebo_ros_control">
      <robotNamespace>/steer_bot</robotNamespace>
      <legacyModeNS>false</legacyModeNS>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- Base link -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.5 0.3 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="green"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.5 0.3 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="5"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.041666666666666664" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.10833333333333334" iyz="0.0" izz="0.14166666666666664"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="front_steer_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="yellow"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0006583333333333334" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0006583333333333334" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0012500000000000002"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="front_steer_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_steer_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.2 0 0.16999999999999998"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="10.0" lower="-3.141592653589793" upper="3.141592653589793" velocity="5.0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <gazebo reference="front_steer_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>
  <link name="rear_wheel_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.0375"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="yellow"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.0375"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.03125"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.5152994791666665e-05" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.5152994791666665e-05" iyz="0.0" izz="2.197265625e-05"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="rear_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="rear_wheel_link"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5707963267948966 0 0" xyz="-0.2 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>
 
  <gazebo reference="rear_wheel_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>
  <link name="front_right_steer_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0006583333333333334" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0006583333333333334" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0012500000000000002"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="front_right_steer_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_right_steer_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.2 -0.2 0.16999999999999998"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="10.0" lower="-0.7853981633974483" upper="0.7853981633974483" velocity="5.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="front_right_wheel_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.08" radius="0.15"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.08" radius="0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0061583333333333325" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0061583333333333325" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01125"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="front_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="front_right_steer_link"/>
    <child link="front_right_wheel_link"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5707963267948966 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.16999999999999998"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>
  
  <gazebo reference="front_right_steer_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="front_right_wheel_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>
  <link name="front_left_steer_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0006583333333333334" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0006583333333333334" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0012500000000000002"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="front_left_steer_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_left_steer_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.2 0.2 0.16999999999999998"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="10.0" lower="-0.7853981633974483" upper="0.7853981633974483" velocity="5.0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="front_left_wheel_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.08" radius="0.15"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.08" radius="0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0061583333333333325" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0061583333333333325" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01125"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="front_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="front_left_steer_link"/>
    <child link="front_left_wheel_link"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5707963267948966 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.16999999999999998"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>
<robot>
```

from this i want to extract `box size` in `<link name="base_link">` and `radius` in `<link name="front_right_wheel_link">`

i tried with this python code but i am unable to extract `radius`

```
for base_link in root.findall('link/visual/geometry/box'):
    value = base_link.get('size')
    print(value)

rad = root.findall("radius[@name='front_right_wheel_link']/visual/geometry/cylinder")   
print(rad)
```

but here rad only gives me `[]`
appreciate if someone can help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION.

```
rad = root.findall("link[@name='front_right_wheel_link']/visual/geometry/cylinder")
for radius in rad:
    r = radius.attrib['radius']
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of

```
radius[@name='front_right_wheel_link']/visual/geometry/cylinder
```

you want

```
link[@name='front_right_wheel_link']/visual/geometry/cylinder/@radius
```

(It might also need a leading "//", but I don't know the python API).

Comment: i get an exception

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: File "param_list.py", line 22, in <module>
    xml_parsing()
  File "param_list.py", line 18, in xml_parsing
    rad = root.findall("link[@name='front_right_wheel_link']/visual/geometry/cylinder/@radius")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 395, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 368, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
KeyError: '@'